# How can I make my classes more platform-independent?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a problem. I've written a GPS module that can detect the type of the message on the fly and configure them if needed. I've done it by composition of several classes. To make code a little more independent from the platform (stm32) I created a `IStreamDevice` interface that has baic i/o operations. It works. Everything appers to be great, but the classs are apparently coupled. That't why I have several question:

1. How can I avoid the passing IStreamDevice to all devices?
2. How can I make the whole design more platform-independent (and os-independent)? We have plans to move to another OS in the nearest future. It is POSIX compliant. I think I will be able to implement my `IStreamDevice` interface there (the buses I can aend up using are UART and SPI. In my current version I use only UART). Am I wrong?

   ```
    class IStreamDevice
       {
               public:
               virtual ~IStreamDevice() {}
               virtual uint32_t read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) = 0;
               virtual uint32_t write(const uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) = 0;    
               virtual uint32_t bytesToRead() const = 0;
               virtual uint32_t bytesToWrite() const = 0;  
       };

       class GPSModule {
       public:

           GPSModule(periph::IStreamDevice *source);
           ~GPSModule();

           void turnDevice1Messages();
           void turnDevice2Messages();
           void configureDevice1(...);
           void configureDevice2(...);
           void Scan();

       private:
           Device1Configurator *_device1_configurator;
           Device2Configurator *_device2_configurator;
           StreamDeviceScanner*_scanner;
           periph::IStreamDevice *_source;
       };

       GPSModule::GPSModule(periph::IStreamDevice *source): _source(source)
       {
           _scanner= new StreamDeviceScanner(_source);
           _device1_configurator = new Device1Configurator(_source);
           _device2_configurator = new Device2Configurator(_source);
       }

       GPSModule::~GPSModule()
       {
           delete _scanner;
       }

       void GPSModule::Scan()
       {
           _scanner->Scan();
       }

       void GPSModule::turnDevice1Messages()   {
           _device1_configurator->turnMessages();
       }

       class StreamDeviceScanner{
       public:
           StreamDeviceScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source);
           ~StreamDeviceScanner();
           void Scan();

       private:
           typedef enum
           {
               WAITING_SYNC,
               WAITING_DEVICE1_MSG,
               WAITING_DEVICE2_MSG
           } states_t;

           periph::IStreamDevice *_source;
           ProtocolScanner *_protocol_scanner;
           states_t _state;
       private:

           states_t _catchSync();
           uint32_t _read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t length) { return _source->read(data,length); }
           uint32_t _bytesToRead() const { return _source->bytesToRead(); }
       };

       StreamDeviceScanner::StreamDeviceScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source):
       _source(source),
       _state(WAITING_SYNC)
       {
           _protocol_scanner = new ProtocolScanner(source);
       }


       StreamDeviceScanner::~StreamDeviceScanner()
       {
           delete _protocol_scanner;
       }


       void StreamDeviceScanner::Scan()
       {
           while  (_source->bytesToRead()) {

                   switch (_state)
                   {
                       case WAITING_SYNC:
                           _state = _catchSync();

                       break;

                       case WAITING_DEVICE1_MSG:
                           _protocol_scanner->Device1Scan()
       _state = WAITING_SYNC;

                       break;

                       case WAITING_DEVICE2_MSG:
                           _protocol_scanner->Device2Scan() 
       _state = WAITING_SYNC;
                       break;
                   }

           }
       }

       class ProtocolScanner {
       private:
           Device1Scanner *_Device1Scanner;
           Device2Scanner *_Device2Scanner;
       public:
           ProtocolScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source)
           {
               _Device1Scanner = new Device1Scanner(source);
               _Device2Scanner = new Device2Scanner(source);
           }

           ~ProtocolScanner()
           {
               delete _Device1Scanner;
               delete _Device1Scanner;
           }

           bool Device1Scan() const { return _Device1Scanner->Scan(); }
           bool Device2Scan() const { return _Device2Scanner->Scan(); }
       };

       class Device1Scanner {
       public:
           Device1Scanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source);
           ~Device1Scanner();
           bool Scan();

       private:
           enum { BUFFER_LENGTH = 8192 };

           typedef enum {
               Waiting_Header,
               Waiting_Payload,
               Waiting_Checksum
           } state_t;


           uint8_t _buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];

           periph::IStreamDevice *_source;

           state_t _state;

           Device1Parser *_destination;
           Device1Scanner::NovatelMessage _message;

       private:
           uint32_t _read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) { return _source->read(data,size); }
           const uint32_t _bytesToRead() const { return _source->bytesToRead(); }

           bool _receiveHeader();
           bool _receivePayload();
           bool _receiveChecksum();
           bool _validChecksum() const;

       };
   ```

   `Device2Scanner` looks exactly the same. I'd like to hear everything that anyone has to say about the design.

Comment: Please send me a snail mail message once you are done editing this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any inherent problem with your design. Your `IStreamWriter` interface seems like a proper abstraction of the underlying bus, without being dependent on specific bus details. That complies with the Dependency Inversion principle and with design-by-contract approach. I also don't see tight coupling in your classes. You're accessing the bus via its handler, according to the interface specification, without dependency on the implementation of the actual bus handling class.

There is nothing platform dependent in the shown code. If the bus handling differs per platform, there is not much you can do except providing a different implementations for `IStreamWriter` according to platform.

Comment: So there is no elegant way to avoid passing IStreamWriter to all class members? When I look at the code I seriously doubt that It can't be done better. Am I thinking too much? As I've written above passing IStreamDevice to all members gives me a headache.

Comment: @enter_the_bot Well, you have to link **somehow** the different objects, right? There are not many options here. The `StreamWriter` can be passed your way; it can be global (usually, it's a bad idea but it depends on the environment and context). You can also have an external storage object to store your `StreamWriter`(s) and query the storage internally from wherever you need - but it saves you nothing and it's a serious over-engineering, you'll just need to connect your users to this storage instead of to the actual `StreamWriter`

Comment: One more remark - usually the more requirements you pose on your software, the more overhead you'll have (it can be performance, complexity or any other type of impact) . Here it is the need to connect your entities explicitly to the `StreamWriter` and the need to write interface (this is the most important part and you're ok with it) - IMHO, a small price to pay for modularity and platform-independence that you gain.